# Converting datetime variable format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help in converting a DateTime variable with format mmm dd yyyy 
to a Datetime variable with format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: When you did a Google search for "SQL Server format date", did you find *anything at all*?

Comment: @ Siyual SQLserver 2016

Comment: have a look here : http://www.karaszi.com/SQLServer/info_datetime.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your datetime variable is a `VARCHAR` - this can be directly cast via `CONVERT`:

```
Declare @YourVariable Varchar (15) = 'JAN 01 1996'

Select Convert(Date, @YourVariable)
```

> 1996-01-01

Comment: ..No its not varchar ,my datetime variable is DATETIME

Comment: I don't understand your question, then.  `DATETIME` data types don't have a format.  Are you wanting to return the data in that format?  (Even if you are, my answer is still perfectly valid...)

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
Select CAST('Sep 07 2016' AS DATE)
```

Returns

```
2016-09-07
```